# value of $6q$ according to given conditions

Tags: algebra-precalculus

let $<a_n>$ define an AP with common difference $d$ and $<b_n>$ be a GP with ratio $q$ where $0<q<1$ and let $a_1=d,b_1=d^2$ also  $$\frac{a_1^2+a_2^2+a_3^2}{b_1+b_2+b_3}$$ is an integer then what is the value of $6q$ i think its $1$ but cant get how to proceed.

Comment: For $q={1\over 2}$ the ratio is 4... So a solution is $6q=3$

Comment: So if i assume q=1/6 then it becomes $1$

Comment: The value for the ratio comes to be $1 + 4 + 9 \over 1+q+q^2$ so, for $q={1 \over 6}$ it is not an integer as its value is $504 \over 43$

Comment: Anyway, you can find $9$ values of $q$ for which the condition holds (just put ${14 \over 1+q+q^2}=5...13$, but I think the only rational solution is $q={1 \over 2}$

Comment: Okay thanks....